# How can I tell VASP 5.2 is compiled with FFTW3?

Tags: fftw, compiling

When VASP 5 was released, the performance was mostly slower than our make of VASP 4.6. I wrote it off as an optimization issue, and went on in my life. Then, in VASP 5.2, with the release notes, I realized that the it was all due to slower FFT, and is now fixed. Is there any way for me, as a user, to tell if the VASP make that I am using is built with the faster FFTW?

Comment: If you are still working with VASP and run into any questions, you might be interested in [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

- Ask whoever built it. :)
- Run strings vasp | grep -i fft and see if there's evidence of the version buried in the executable.
- Run ldd vasp and look for a dynamically linked fft library.  This last option is unlikely to produce results because you're more likely to have a static FFTW library (if I recall the build process for FFTW correctly).

Comment: To expand on this answer, you could also try: `nm vasp | grep fftw` to take a look for some of the FFTW symbols assuming that the executable hasn't been stripped.

Comment: That's a great point, Aron, though I recommend `grep -i` in this context.